# What does 'the lower cover' mean in a lattice

Tags: terminology, lattice-orders

I am working through a problem inspired by this unanswered question:

[Help understanding a proof about finite lattice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2423886/help-understanding-a-proof-about-finite-lattice?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The hint from the book says "let $b$ be the lower cover of $a$ in the chain $C$".

What do they mean by "the lower cover of a"? Do they mean the element above $a$ in the chain? Or is there a definition of "lower cover" that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Definition*** ([Schröder 2016](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=66oqDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA6)): For elements $a, b$ in a poset, $a$ is a *lower cover* of $b$ iff $a < b$ and no element $c$ satisfies $a < c < b$.

So for a non-minimal element $a$ in a finite chain, there is a unique lower cover of $a$.

Comment: It seems, though, in English we do not say "there is the lower cover" but instead say "there is a unique lower cover".